# Need to loop through set to find different objects by attributes

Tags: java

I have a  set, i.e

```
Set<FitmentData> fitmentDataSet;
```

this set has around 5 objects.

```
public class FitmentData implements Comparable<FitmentData> 
{
private String year;
private String make;
private String model;

}
```

Now, I need to iterate through this set and find out how many different vehicles this set has comparing year,make and model.I was thinking to get the first object and loop through set by comparing year, make, model. Is there a better way to deal this?

Note: My sample fitment object looks like

```
new FitementDate("2005", "honda","crv" );
new FitementDate("2005", "honda","crv" );
new FitementDate("2005", "honda","crv" );
new FitementDate("2005", "mazda","cx-5" );
new FitementDate("2005", "subaru","forester" );
```

Comment: If you are using Java 8, refer to Stream API - groupBy()

Comment: If you implemented `equals` and `hashCode` correctly, there would only be three items in the set.

Comment: set don't keep duplicate values, try `List` instead

Comment: What implementation of `Set` do you use? A custom one? As @Flying Zombie noted, a Set shouldn't provide support for duplicates unless it is mentioned/choosen for explicitly

Comment: thank you guys, my intention is to take different vehicles into another list or set.

Comment: @n247s, @Flying Zombie : Set can't handle duplicity unless `hashCode` and `equals` is correctly implemented on object (as pointed out by Makoto)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments: "A set does not contain duplicates", e.g., if you are using a `HashSet` and you implement the `hashCode` and `equals` method correctly. If you are using a `TreeSet` you also have to implement the `compareTo` method correctly (and implement the `Comparable` interface). Regarding the implementation of these methods have a look at other StackOverflow posts (there are many more):

- [What issues should be considered when overriding equals and hashCode in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/what-issues-should-be-considered-when-overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java)
- [Hashcode and Equals for Hashset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396939/hashcode-and-equals-for-hashset)
- [java TreeSet: comparing and equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30757567/java-treeset-comparing-and-equality)

The iteration through the `Set` (or any `Collection`) can be done using different approaches: `for`, `foreach`, `lambda`, ...:

- [How to Iterate over a Set/HashSet without an Iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12455737/how-to-iterate-over-a-set-hashset-without-a-iterator)

Comment: A set does not contain duplicates true.  objects inside a set can have same data(mycase).                                                                                                 let me tell you my requirement again. i just want objects from set which has different year, make and model.thanks in advance.

Comment: If you don't have a `Set` in a Java sense, maybe you should talk and use a `List`? And then use the iterations mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12455737/how-to-iterate-over-a-set-hashset-without-a-iterator, because these work for all Java `Collections`.